# Dynamically add input field with select option tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mysql, html

I am trying to generate resume for user using jQuery code. What I am trying, user click on select tag and chose year o experience option, based on their choice number of input field is open. like: companyname1, location1 or companyname2, location2.

Script:

```
<script> 
 $(docment).ready(function(){
     $("#experienceNo").on("change",function(){
     var numInputs = $(this).val();
     $('#experienceSection').html('');
     for(var i=0; i < numInputs; i++)
     {
         var j = i*1;
         $('<div class="form-group"><label for="" class="col-4 col-form-label">Company Name '+j+'</label><div class="col-6"><input type="text" name="companyname[]" class="form-control" required></div></div>');
     }
   });
 });
 </script>
```

HTML:

```
<h4>Experience Section</h4>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="experienceNo" class="col-4 col-form-label"> No of company add for experience</label>
  <div class="col-6">
    <select name="experienceNo" id="experienceNo" class="custom-select mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0"> 
    <option value="">Select Value</option>`enter code here`
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
    </div>
  </div>
 <div id="experienceSection"></div>
 <div class="form-group row"> 
 <div class="col-6"> 
 <button type="submit" name="genrate" class="btn btn-
 primary">Genrate</button>
```

Comment: And now what is your question? By the way, do you realize `j=i*1` is the same as `j=i`, so you might as well use `i` where you use `j`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code will be helpful to you,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#experienceNo").on("change",function(){
     var numInputs = $(this).val();
     $('#experienceSection').html('');
     for(var i=0; i < numInputs; i++)
     {
         var j = i*1;
         var $section =  $('<div class="form-group"><label for="" class="col-4 col-form-label">Company Name '+j+'</label><div class="col-6"><input type="text" name="companyname[]" class="form-control" required></div></div>');
         $('#experienceSection').append($section);
     }
   });
 });
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <h4>Experience Section</h4>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="experienceNo" class="col-4 col-form-label"> No of company add for experience</label>
  <div class="col-6">
    <select name="experienceNo" id="experienceNo" class="custom-select mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0"> 
    <option value="">Select Value</option>`enter code here`
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
    </div>
  </div>
 <div id="experienceSection"></div>
 <div class="form-group row"> 
 <div class="col-6"> 
 <button type="submit" name="genrate" class="btn btn-
 primary">Genrate</button>
```

Make sure that you need to append each dynamically created div to `experienceSection`

Comment: @lucky nath if it is working for please accept it as your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
i am trying this code but i still not get output.
```

### Here it is:

```
 Script:
     $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#experienceNo").on("change",function(){
     var numInputs = $(this).val();
     $('#experienceSection').html('');
     for(var i=0; i < numInputs; i++)
     {
         var j = i*1;
         var $section =$('<div class="form-group"><label for="" class="col-4 
         col-form-label">Company Name '+j+' </label><div class="col-6"><input 
         type="text" name="companyname[]" class="form-control" required></div>
         </div> 
         <div class="form-group"><label for="" class="col-4 col-form-
         label">Location '+j+' </label><div class="col-6"><input type="text" 
         name="location[]" class="form-control" required></div></div><hr>');

     $('#experienceSection').append($section);
      }
   });
 });

 HTML:
  <form>
  <h4>Experience Section</h4>
  <div>
  <label> No of company add for experience</label>
  <select name="experienceNo" id="experienceNo"> 
  <option value="">Select Value</option>
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  </select>
 </div>
 <div id="experienceSection"></div>
 <div> 
 <button type="submit" name="genrate" class="btn btnprimary">Genrate</button>
</div>
```